# Using java "for each" and "continue" in a loop

Tags: java, loops

I have a big method which looks like this :

```
for (Person person : persons) {
   if (!person.isValid()) {
      continue;
   }
   ....
   boolean isDeleted = deletePersonFromDB1(person);
   if (!isDeleted) {
     continue;
   }
   ....

}
```

Basically I want to delete a list of persons from differents DB sources. If any operation fails, I want to continue to next person.
I would like to simplify like this and put my business logic inside a method :

```
for (Person person : persons) {
    checkValidityAndDelete(person)
}
```

But unfortunately, I cannot use the word `continue` inside my method `checkValidityAndDelete`

Comment: You can have that method `return` a `boolean`, and then do some `if (result) { continue; }` type thing?

Comment: Off topic but why would you want to continue working with a `person` object after it has been deleted?

Comment: Or in fact, if you're doing your business logic as simple as you're making out there (and that method is just a `void`) you can just `return` from it wherever you would `continue`.  This will cause the method to terminate, and the loop to start the next iteration.

Comment: You should break this into multiple methods.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I've seen similar logic for things such as event publication, logging, now-defunct resource cleanup, etc.

Comment: @user2478398 Sure I was thinking about that too but then it would make more sense to use the `if` to do that and not to call `continue`. This looks like a bad (over) use of `break/continue`

Answer (score 0):

Make your `checkValidityAndDelete` method return a boolean to indicate whether the person is both valid and was deleted:

```
private boolean checkValidityAndDelete(Person person) {
  return person.isValid() && deletePersonFromDB1(person);
}
```

So, if `checkValidityAndDelete` returns `false`, you can then `continue`, if it returns `true`, you can proceed with the rest of your code logic. You can also achieve this without the use of `continue` if you wish to do so:

```
for (Person person : persons) {
  if(checkValidityAndDelete(person)) { // If the person is valid, 
    // perform logic...
  }
  // if not valid, skip if, and continue to next person...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you're looking to pull *everything* in the loop out to another method is simply `return`~ing from it to trigger the method to stop.

```
public void checkValidity(final Person person) {
    if (person.something) {
        return;
        // From the calling loop, this will act as a continue
        // since the method call would stop, and so the next
        // loop iteration would start.
    }
    // Do some more stuff
}
```